# Check if update has happened correctly in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a simple cursor and an update query as follows

```
declare
...
cursor test_update is
...
begin
for c1 in test_update
loop
update ...
where column_1=column_2
end loop ;
end;
```

Now my question is if that update has happened succesfully then i have to do a `delete` operation on a particular table. Is that posibble? Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: it is possible, you can implement this via trigger or in a delete statement that follows your update within current procedure.

Comment: Hi Bulat i know that i can use `delete from table_1 where cre_date <= (sysdate -7) ` but i want this to be done only if the `for loop` successfully executes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the 'update has happened successfully' means that one or more rows were updated, you can test that with the [`SQL%ROWCOUNT` implicit cursor attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/sql_cursor.htm):

```
for c1 in test_update
loop
  update ...
  where column1=column2;

  if sql%rowcount > 0 then
    delete ... ;
  end if;
end loop;
```

If you need to do the delete after the loop then you can add the row count to a variable, to get a running total of affected rows, and test that at the end. The row count will only be meaningful straight after the update and only reflects what was done in the update in that iteration of the loop.

Comment: Hi Alex thnx a lot for the answer, do you feel it is better to use if withinn for loop or after for loop

Comment: @user2647888 - depends what you're deleting. If each delete is based on the just-updated records then inside the loop; but if you're doing a single delete based on sysdate (as in your comment) then doing it once at the end probably makes more sense. Not really sure what you're doing though, or why you're using a loop...

Comment: no basically what i'm deleting is all the records in a table which are older than 7 days so can you please help me with the correct syntax `for c1 in test_update
loop
update ..
where columns1=column2
commit;
end loop;

if sql%rowcount > 0
then
delete from backup_table
where cre_date <= (sysdate -7);
end if;`

Comment: @user2647888 - sorry, I don't understand what you're asking for, or what the link is between the update and the delete. Maybe you can add some more information to the question to explain what you need? (You're missing a semicolon in the code in your last comment and in the question though, after `column2`).

Comment: very sorry as i have very bad presentation skills. All i want to do is check if the for loop has executed successfully I'm ok even if it has updated only one row but i want my for loop to end correctly .if it has ended properly then i want to use my delete statement after the for loop

Comment: @user2647888 - what does 'not successful' look like? If it throws an exception then you won't reach the delete after the loop anyway. DO you just want to check that the cursor found something so it went around the loop at least once?

Comment: ok ok got it i just want to know the syntax what to put if im putting it after the for loop

Comment: In that case you do not have to do anything. The default exception handling in pl/sql will make sure the delete is not executed if the update fails with an error.